# Error: More than one instance of overloaded function "sqrt" matches the argument list. What that?

Tags: c, math

In my homework for my C class, we have to write a program that checks if an integer is prime. I am getting an error at the sqrt() function. My professor told me that num must be an integer and we must use the sqrt() function. I thought the problem was that the sqrt() function can't be used on an integer but my professor told me that it can, and that I was getting an error from something else. Do you guys see the problem?

```
int primality(int num)
{

int isprime;

    /*check if num is prime*/
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
            isprime = 0; /*is not prime*/
        else 
            isprime = 1; /*is prime*/
    }

    if (isprime == 0)
        return 0;
    elseif (isprime == 1)
        return 1;
}
```

EDIT:
Yes I am using math.h and compiling as C code.

The error msg is "Error: More than one instance of overloaded function "sqrt" matches the argument list.

Comment: And the error message you got was... ? Without seeing that, (a) did you include math.h? (b) did you link with libm? (I'm ignoring any other mistakes in the program, @CarlNorum has pointed out one)

Comment: In this code you will return from every iteration of the loop. In other words you will only do one iteration. This code simply tests whether your number is even or odd. By the way, the corrected function should be named `isprime`. And can't you use `bool` rather than `int` for a logical value?

Comment: How are you compiling? I'm smelling `C++` in the error message.

Comment: I am using Visual C++ to write and compile my code. Could that be the problem? I have never had any trouble using it before.

Comment: You can rewrite `i <= sqrt(num)` as `i * i <= num`

Comment: Suggestion:  Though it won't affect the logic of your program, you can eliminate the if / elseif block at the end of the function and replace it with a single line of C++ code consisting of a single reserved word, a single variable name and a semicolon.  The reserved word and variable name should be separated by a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C language does not have "overloads". My bet is that you are compiling your code as C++, not C. If you're using GCC, compile with `gcc`, not `g++`. If you are using Visual Studio, there is an option in the properties of the project:

1. right click on your project
2. click properties
3. click on C/C++
4. click on advanced
5. set the property "compile as" to C Code (/TC)

In either case, name your file with a `.c` extension (*lowercase* 'c').

Indeed, in C there is only one `sqrt`, defined as

```
double sqrt(double);
```

and integers convert to double.

Comment: I am using Visual C++ and have the file named with a .c extension. I will look around in the settings for the Compile as C Code option though.

Comment: @Petefic: I already had this problem. VC++ doesn't seem to care what extension your file is, and it really seems you're compiling to C++ code here.

Comment: There is no `sqrt(int,...)` in `cmath` so you will have to cast your ints to double like this `sqrt((double)num)` to match one of sqrt() definitions. Also you are using C++ as you have declared and initialized `int i = 2` directly in your `for loop` head section. :)

Comment: @ludesign: Nope, that `for` loop usage is standard C.

Comment: @R.. It is standard in C99, adopted from C++; but in C89 (ANSI) it is not. Anyway, I stand corrected. :)

Comment: ANSI C is C99. The ANSI and ISO standards are aligned; people are generally just less US-centric than they were 20 years ago so we usually say ISO now instead of ANSI. C89 is simply an obsolete version of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to `return 1` inside your loop - it needs to be after the loop completes.  Your professor is right that `sqrt(num)` will work - `num` will be promoted to `double` automatically - C has rules for type changes in function calls, etc.  You do need to include `math.h` if you haven't done that elsewhere in your program - what error are you getting?

Comment: There is another problem—you actually want <= sqrt (otherwise, 9 is prime). And since doubles aren't precise, you need to deal with that too.

Comment: @derobert: I don't see any inexactness issues to deal with here... If `x` is a perfect square no wider than 53 bits, `sqrt(x)` has an exact result, and IEEE 754 mandates that the exact result be returned.

Comment: @R..: Even assuming IEEE 754, int can be 64 bits.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I mentioned the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong right here:

```
    if (num % i == 0)
        return 0; /*is not prime*/
    else 
        return 1; /*is prime*/
```

If you think about it, if the number is not divisible by two, your function immediately returns `1`.

You are `return`ing too early. Remember that a `return` essentially stops your function and breaks out of it.

Instead, try to break out *only* when the number is composite and return `True` *only* when you are sure that it is prime.

Just as a side note, your function will register squares of primes (i.e. `9`, `25`, `49`) as prime because you are using the `<` sign in your `for` loop.

Change it to a `<=` sign, as that will account for the square root being the only divisor of the number.

Comment: Well, mostly done the homework, as you haven't yet dealt with FP not being precise. `(int)(sqrt(100)) == 9` may be true, for all we know.

Comment: Sorry, it's an automatic reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include <math.h>`?

Also, according to your function 1, 2, and 3 come back as not prime... Might want to fix that. I'd offer more help but it sounds like this is for homework and I'd rather not just give you the answer (some universities consider it cheating).

Comment: Since you didn't post what errors you were getting, that was just first one I would think of (even in my own code I forget an include every now and then).

Comment: If you're getting an error on sqrt(num) with num as an int, you could try casting it as a float.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question: sqrt() does not have an overload for int, but it has overloads for both double and float, and so the compiler cannot guess which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sqrt function does not take an integer as a argument. You will want to do

sqrt((double)n) or sqrt((float)n) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you included `#include <math.h>`, you can fix the error of: `for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++)` by changing the `sqrt(num)` to a simple declared variable (like `n, x, i...` ) because `sqrt(num)` already used in the `math.h` library.

Answer (score -2):

the function of `sqrt()` define as `double sqrt(double)` so you're input should be double or float.

To turning an `integer` variable to `float` without change the type use `float( integer_Variable )`

For example in you're code write `i<=sqrt(float(num));`

Comment: Please fix your comment, put code in code-tags and so on.